# Criteria Builder Create new Object In Select Statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, jpql, criteria-api

I was wondering if it's possible to create such query like :

```
em.createQuery(
        "SELECT NEW EmpMenu(p.name, p.department.name) "
            + "FROM Project p ").getResultList();
```

also is it possible to do it via Specification:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
        CriteriaBuilder cb) {


    return ???;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the answer, personally, but did you give it a shot?

Answer (score 41):

Yes, Criteria API does have have construct similar to JPQL constructor expressions. Result class is set via [construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#construct%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...%29) method in CriteriaBuilder.

Your JPQL query expressed as an criteria query is:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb...
CriteriaQuery<EmpMenu> q = cb.createQuery(EmpMenu.class);
  Root<Project> c = q.from(Project.class);
  q.select(cb.construct(EmpMenu.class,
      c.get("name"), c.get("department").get("name")));
```

Comment: GOOD, It's exactly what i wanted! But now i have another question. I use Spring Data and Specification to create queries. From you example i see that i have to call **q.select** , but in Specification select statement is called automatically (bcs you just return the Predicate). Do I have a chance to do it using Specification interface? or i have to create my own repository, call EntityManage and create the query....

Comment: Is it possible to specify an Optional value into the construct() method ? like with a LEFT OUTER JOIN, I would like to retrieve in the select a field, and also create the object even if this field is null.

Comment: I have a DTO that is composed of few fields, and I recently added a List<MyCustomObject> as a field of this DTO. The criteria builder .construct() was working fine, but I need the select statement to create a List in my custom object. I found nothing on the web about how to do this.. if someone passing by know the answer, ill be grateful, thx

Comment: Is it possible to set values to list  field of custom bean class

Comment: I can't use a custom construct when my entity has a jsonb type field. "Unable to locate appropriate constructor on..." the field type jsonb is replacement by instead a real class.

Comment: what if list of arguments increase for construct method say above 7. We obviously can't write such a constructor with huge number of arguments for EmpMenu class

Comment: @harshakumarReddy use tuple query

Comment: @Makky if i do that . then again if i want those values in POJO then i have to use loop to initialize those. don't you think its redundant step

Comment: @harshakumarReddy thats fine. Its IO process. It won't have any performance issue
works a treat though